# separate ribbon configuration for each rest template loadbalance in spring cloud

Tags: spring-boot, load-balancing, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

How to provide separate ribbon configuration for separate rest template?
I know in Feign client we can have separate configuration ,but how we will have separate configuration for separate rest template.
For example :There are 2 services (A) and (B) ,I want to use service A with Roundrobin IRule and B with AvailabilityFilteringRule.
Is there any way to configured for rest template?

Comment: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR2/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html#_customizing_the_ribbon_client

Comment: How to use @Ribbon client for different rest template

Comment: You dont use `@RibbonClient` for different `RestTemplates` you use it to configure separate services.  The `name` attribute can be used to specify the name of the service that the configuration applies to.

Comment: Ohh,I got it now,I did not find those kind of explanation in spring doc of ribbon.Is there any documentation